# iOS validate RSS

Tags: ios, rss, validation

I have an app that reads RSS feeds, is working fine, but I would like to validate the rss link that the user types like [the w3 validator](http://validator.w3.org/feed/)

thanks in advance!
;)

Comment: Would you like to validate it as a feature in your app or is it to make sure the feed is valid before parsing it?

Comment: hi thanks, I would like to make sure is valid before parsing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since RSS is just XML, I'm guessing you're using `NSXMLParser` to parse the feed.

If you implement the `-[NSXMLParserDelegate parser:parseErrorOccurred:]` method, you will be notified if the feed can't be parsed for whatever reason.

The `parser` object in the method contains the line and column number where the error occurred.